# A favourite for some, but a pain for the elite! - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

*So I came up with another probably very stupid riddle, but feel free to have a go!*

> Yet another to test the brain,
>   For they will come without end.
>
> Always take care when you're out,
>   For grace is not with you anymore.
>
> Trains rely on the smallest things,
>   They keep everyone in community.
>
> Many people will come together,
>   Bear witness to life's greatest illusion.
>
> The web spreads wider than most,
>   So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.
>
> There is an author of this madness,
>   However it will not stop with him.
>
> The silver tongue may ramble on,
>   For it only shows you half truths.
>
> For that which is fundamental,
>   It becomes entirely perceptive.
>
> The great heat that we all enjoy,
>   Is only a marker for something out of our control.

**What am I?**

Hint:

> Each paragraph provides a different clue that will only give the answer when they are put together!

Hint 2:

> Paragraphs 5-7 are more command than clue.

Hint 3:

> The answer could be considered a *"who"* or a *"what"*!

Comment: *bear witness, perhaps?

Comment: @feelinferrety I was wondering about that. Could mean "naked person" instead.

Also, there's a big "elements" vibe going on here. I wonder if it has to do with the sun or heat.

Comment: yep suppose to be bear thought I'd checked it all apparently not

Comment: Are you sure this is wordplay? I kind of have an idea to the answer, and its not a typical riddle answer at all but can't find any wordplay

Comment: actually your correct it probably doesn't have any wordplay as such

Comment: I am not sure why, but I feel this answer should be "Math Problem" :p

Comment: @Paul Karam  - Much as I love maths, its got nothing to do with this one!

Answer (score 4):

**Partial solution ?**

As the first hint tells us,

> "Each paragraph provides a different clue ..."
>  So let's try to find the right word for each paragraph.

```
Yet another to test the brain,
For they will come without end.
```

> This seems like it should be Puzzle, or Riddle, or Question, or Test.
>  I tend to like **TEST** Because Reasons™ - keep reading.

```
Always take care when you’re out,
For grace is not with you anymore.
```

> When you're out, say, on a **TRIP**, an ungraceful thing to do.

```
Trains rely on the smallest things,
They keep everyone in community.
```

> Train tracks are held together by railroad **TIES**.
>  "Blest Be the Tie That Binds" is an old hymn extolling "the fellowship of kindred minds", and is the origin of oft-used expressions of "ties that bind" having that meaning.

```
Many people will come together,
Bear witness to life’s greatest illusion.
```

> Not sure.
>  Other answers have noted that this paragraph seems like watching a movie. Anything where a group of people come to watch something not actually there, like an illusion or a film, would seem to qualify.

```
The web spreads wider than most,
So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.
```

> Hint 2 says this is more command than hint.
>  Presumably it means to go Google something.

```
There is an author of this madness,
However it will not stop with him.
```

> Hint 2 says this is more command than hint.
>  Presumably it means a prominent search result will be the author of whatever-this-is-about, but that's not all there is to find, so keep looking beyond that.

```
The silver tongue may ramble on,
For it only shows you half truths.
```

> Hint 2 says this is more command than hint.
>  Not sure what it's supposed to tell us to do.

```
For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.
```

> No idea.

```
The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.
```

> The great heat is the Sun, and it marks days.
>  This probably means **TIME**.

As for an overall solution,

> I have no idea yet.  I'm not sure if it's just coincidence or if it's by design that the words I feel reasonably confident of are four letters in length and begin with a **T**.

If any of this helps anyone else have an idea of how to fill in the gaps, I'm all ears.

Comment: 5 and 6 are correct in terms of what to do. 2 and 9 nine are along the right lines but not quite the right word!

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> the internet / social media?

Always take care when you’re out,
For grace is not with you anymore.

> Whatever we do can easily be posted online for anyone to see, as everyone has a camera these days

Trains rely on the smallest things,
They keep everyone in community.

> Something to do with data being passed back and forth, enabling us to form an online community - not entirely sure about this one

Many people will come together,
Bear witness to life’s greatest illusion.

> Social media / the internet brings us together. Society is life's greatest illusion, it is entirely in our heads, and yet is something that drives the majority of our actions

The web spreads wider than most,
So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.

> The internet / social media is far reaching, everywhere seems to have access. Knowledge is easily gained from it.

There is an author of this madness,
However it will not stop with him.

> Someone invented the internet / SM, yet now that it's started the genie cannot be put back in the bottle

The silver tongue may ramble on,
For it only shows you half truths.

> Most information found online is biased in some way, yet there is an almost unlimited supply of it regardless of your biases

For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.

> The internet / Social media is becoming a fundamental part of who we are, yet how each person uses it is down to the individual

The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.

> Not sure about this one, we all partake in the internet, and it is out of our control, but even so... this one is the one that gives me doubts about my answer

Comment: I like this answer clearly a lot of thought in it however as you said it doesn't fit the last part too well. Plus you didn't put anything for the first bit, though from what it says I can see why. Good guess but no sorry!

Answer (score 3):

The answer, I believe, is:

> A riddle on Puzzling Stack Exchange, perhaps even this one.

Yet another to test the brain,
For they will come without end.

> Riddles are a way to test the mind, and they are in large numbers on this site.

Always take care when you're out,
For grace is not with you anymore.

> If you plan on answering a riddle, and you decide to have a quick snack before you do so, someone may have already answered correctly before you, and you don't get all the glory you think you deserve. :P

Trains rely on the smallest things,
They keep everyone in community.

> Trains here could refer to trains of answers, i.e., chains of answers, i.e., the list of answers posted by everyone, even the newest members, in the community.

Many people will come together,
Bear witness to life's greatest illusion.

> 311 people (as of writing this) came here to witness this illusion called a riddle!

The web spreads wider than most,
So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.

> This is on the internet, i.e., the World Wide Web or 'Net. The original site, StackOverflow, is used as a way to gain knowledge in a Q&A format.

There is an author of this madness,
However it will not stop with him.

> @BMS21 is the author of this riddle, and they has no control over their riddle anymore since BMS21 is not responsible for the answers to this riddle.
>
>
>  Also, singular they rules! :D

The silver tongue may ramble on,
For it only shows you half truths.

> The silver tongue here is probably a reference to the mouse and keyboard, both of which are used here to create the half truths, or clues, of this riddle.

For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.

> Whatever in this riddle that is absolutely necessary to solve it is debatable, and whatever causes a person to think of the answer is dependent on the person.

The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.

> The heat could refer to that feeling of accomplishment one gets when answering a riddle correctly, and that feeling is a marker of an order to something so complex as a riddle.

Comment: This answer is so cool i feel bad for having to say its wrong! XD I wish I had thought of that when writing!

Comment: @BMS21 I'm slightly disappointed that this is not the right answer, but I'm happy that you like it anyways. :D Meta-stuff is fun! :P

Answer (score 3):

Partial Solution:
I've looked at others posts and think I have some answers:

Trains rely on the smallest things,
They keep everyone in community.

> This sound weird but is it **connections**? Maybe a connecting word (on, or, in, etc...)

Many people will come together,
Bear witness to life’s greatest illusion.

> This maybe be talking about **freedom**. All people come under some form of government, whether free or not everyone conforms to some system!

For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.

> Going along the sciency theme, is this **gravity**? Fundamental to both physics and life yet it entirely depends on where you are!

The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.

> Rubio said "time" and that's "not quite right". So since it mentions what sounds like the sun is it a **Year**?

Comment: Nice one! 2/4 The trains is correct (second part btw) and so is great heat! The other two are a nice try but not correct unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

Very unsure about this one, but maybe my answer will spur someone to get it right. I'm hoping I wasn't completely off the mark.

The answer is:

> The sun/solar eclipse

Always take care when you’re out,
For grace is not with you anymore.

> Being outside can cause sunburn

Trains rely on the smallest things,
They keep everyone in community.

> This one doesn't really fit, maybe it has to do with the chemical composition.

Many people will come together,
Bear witness to life’s greatest illusion.

> The solar eclipse in a month will cause an illusion of nighttime during the day. People are travelling to see it.

The web spreads wider than most,
So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.

> The eclipse is happening all across the U.S. for the first time in a long time. There is a big opportunity for viewing.

There is an author of this madness,
However it will not stop with him.

> The moon? Maybe this means that it will keep moving.

The silver tongue may ramble on,
For it only shows you half truths.

> Moon is deceiving us into believing it is night.

For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.

> The sun is fundamental, but it will 'disappear' for a little while.

The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.

> For the viewing of the eclipse, the sun only exists to mark the coming of darkness.

EDIT:
My answer was wrong, but I came back to take another look. Here are some thoughts:

Yet another to test the brain,
For they will come without end.
Always take care when you’re out,
For grace is not with you anymore.

> Reads as some kind of 'evil' coming to get you. Could be referring to impure thoughts or temptation. Maybe it has to do with marriage? "Take care when you're out" because you don't want to cheat on your partner.

Trains rely on the smallest things,
They keep everyone in community.

> Steam? Coal? Wood? These could make sense if you approach the sentence from a literal view. Coal would be most likely.

Many people will come together,
Bear witness to life’s greatest illusion.

> Relates to the 'community' referenced in the previous paragraph. Life's greatest illusion is innocence, brother.

The web spreads wider than most,
So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.

> op said this is supposed to be a command. The obvious message would be that "you probably don't know this answer, you will need to learn more by reading online".

There is an author of this madness,
However it will not stop with him.
The silver tongue may ramble on,
For it only shows you half truths.

> These are also supposed to be commands, but I'm not sure what they're instructing you to do. They seem to be referring to a person who is spreading whatever evil or illusion the earlier paragraphs refer to.

For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.
The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.

> I have only vague thoughts here. Words like "fundamental" and "great heat" give off a science-y vibe, but I can't really relate them. Second half could again be referencing something we enjoy but shouldn't.

Comment: Interesting thought, the train part kinda messes with it and you also choose not to include the first paragraph which may or may not help. Sorry but no!

Comment: @BMS21 Ah whoops. I must have missed it when I was copying the lines. Maybe I'll give it another attempt later.

Comment: @BMS21 Added some new thoughts below. Anything close to the mark?

Comment: 5 is basically correct but that might be one of the more obvious points, and the last couple are science-y for sure!

Comment: @BMS21 Ahhh jeez, I thought I would have been close on some of those points. So as I understand it: you need to find the right word for each paragraph, then use those words to find the final word that relates to the title? Or does the final answer relate to each paragraph as well?

Comment: It relates to the title yeah but not to each paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Some guesses as to the component words. I'm not quite sure of the direction this is heading yet. The title seems to suggest something along the lines of...

> ... free speech.

1: Yet another to test the brain, For they will come without end.

> Questions?

2: Always take care when you’re out, For grace is not with you anymore.

> Stupid tangent, but is it *will*?

EDIT: no, I now think this means

> Fall

3: Trains rely on the smallest things, They keep everyone in community.

> Trains rely on tracks, or lines, but in this context, I think the answer is *link*

4: Many people will come together, Bear witness to life’s greatest illusion.

> According to the Special Theory of Relativity, time is an illusion.

5 (command): The web spreads wider than most, So cast a net for a gain in knowledge.

> We need to Google something (already established as correct)

6 (command): There is an author of this madness, However it will not stop with him.

> The author found in the search result is a hint to the answer (already established as correct)

7 (command): The silver tongue may ramble on,
For it only shows you half truths.

> Silver tongues and half truths suggest the word *lie*.

8: For that which is fundamental,
It becomes entirely perceptive.

> The word 'fundamental' suggests a musical note or pitch?

9: The great heat that we all enjoy,
Is only a marker for something out of our control.

> We know this is **Year**, thanks to user39569's post.

Comment: Some of the points are correct but the answer isn't. Nice try!

Comment: Have I added any correct answers, or is it just the already-established parts that are correct?